# C# Lambda Problem

Tags: c#, lambda

Probably something simple, but as I'm new to lambda expressions, the problem evades me:

```
m => m.contactID == contactID && m.primaryAddress == true && (m.addressTypeID == 2 || m.addressTypeID == 3)
```

I tried to use that lambda expression but I receive an invalid operator. Is there a way to simplify this so that it would work?

**Edit:**

The equivolent sql query would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM Contact
WHERE contactID = 3
AND primaryAddress = 1
AND (addressTypeID = 2 OR addressTypeID = 3)
```

I have a repository function defined like so:

```
public E Single(Expression<Func<E, bool>> where)
{
    return objectSet.Single<E>(where);
}
```

I'm passing the lambda expression above into this function:

```
myRepository.Single(m => m.contactID == contactID && m.primaryAddress == true && (m.addressTypeID == 2 || m.addressTypeID == 3));
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you post some more information/code?

Comment: Also, please post the full text of the error you're receiving.

Comment: is `m.primaryAddress != null` (or `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.primaryAddress)`) what you meant? EDIT: if primaryAddress is integer, you cannot compare it to true/false.

Comment: Is this a compiler error, or a runtime error?  If runtime, it's most likely that there is more than a single element...

Comment: Runtime - I'll double check but I'm pretty darn positive its returning only 1 item.

Comment: @Chris: Is the exception "InvalidOperationException"?  If so, there is more than one element being found by the query.  See the link (Queryable.Single) for details - that's the exception .Single() raises when there's more than one match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are receiving an `InvalidOperationException`, the most likely cause is that there is more than one record that matches your criteria.

[Queryable.Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156472.aspx) will raise `InvalidOperationException` if there is more than a single correct value.  In this case, try using [.First(m => ..)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535183.aspx) instead:

```
myRepository.First(m => 
      m.contactID == contactID && 
      m.primaryAddress == true && 
      (m.addressTypeID == 2 || m.addressTypeID == 3)
    );
```

This will return the first matching result, if there are more than one.  If you need to handle no matches, look into [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549141.aspx) (which will return null if there are no matches).

Answer (score 1):

m.primaryAddress == true looks suspicious. is m.primaryAddress really a bool property?

Comment: its a bit operator in the database

Comment: It could be, perhaps would be better named IsPrimaryAddress.

But really, You should just write "&& m.primaryAddress &&" instead of "&& m.primaryAddress == true &&", since it is a bool.

Comment: a bit operator? is it nullable?

Answer (score 0):

`m => (m.contactID == contactID && m.primaryAddress == true && (m.addressTypeID == 2 || m.addressTypeID == 3))` is merely a boolean expression.

You need to do something like
 `list.Remove(m => (m.contactID == contactID && m.primaryAddress == true && (m.addressTypeID == 2 || m.addressTypeID == 3)))` etc

This says take each item in my list as `m` if this returns true remove `m`

**Edit OP reposted while I was writing that answer**

I would write this like this as to your syntax.

`Func Filter<var, bool> = m => (m.contactID == contactID && m.primaryAddress == true && (m.addressTypeID == 2 || m.addressTypeID == 3))`

then pass Filter into your `myrepository.Single(Filter)`

Answer (score 0):

From your SQL query, should it be:

```
m => m.contactID == contactID && m.primaryAddress == 1 && (m.addressTypeID == 2 || m.addressTypeID == 3)
```